# How to Slice List as bytes range Chunk?

Tags: python, list, range, slice, chunks

I have total Size for example 1037

and chunk size for example 50

i want a list contain range such as:

['0 - 50' , '50 - 100' , '100 - 150' , ....]

to end (1037)

how to do this Please ?

i try use:

```
n = 1037


chunk_size = 50
x = [f'{sa} - {sa + chunk_size }' for sa in range(0, (n - (n % chunk_size)), chunk_size+1)] + [f'{(n // chunk_size) * chunk_size } - {n}' if ((n // chunk_size) * chunk_size ) < n else '']
print(x)
```

I got:

```
['0 - 50', '51 - 101', '102 - 152', '153 - 203', '204 - 254', '255 - 305', '306 - 356', '357 - 407', '408 - 458', '459 - 509', '510 - 560', '561 - 611', '612 - 662', '663 - 713', '714 - 764', '765 - 815', '816 - 866', '867 - 917', '918 - 968', '969 - 1019', '1000 - 1037']
```

but after 1019 should be `'1020 - 1037'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one less for each chunk you calculated for the last pair.  Just add them back. see the `int(n / chunk_size)` below.

```
x = [f'{sa} - {sa + chunk_size }' for sa in range(0, (n - (n % chunk_size)), chunk_size+1)] + [f'{(n // chunk_size) * chunk_size + int(n / chunk_size)} - {n}' if ((n // chunk_size) * chunk_size ) < n else '']
```

Comment: i try it with:

chunk_size = 5242880

n = 34252464

but not working fine :(

Comment: @Kakarotto `['0 - 5242880', '5242881 - 10485761', '10485762 - 15728642', '15728643 - 20971523', '20971524 - 26214404', '26214405 - 31457285', '31457286 - 34252464']` is this result wrong?

Comment: Sorry all ok,

I see problem from my main script i needd list such as ```['0 - 5242880', '5242880 - 10485760' , '10485760 - {10485760 + chunk_size}'  ....]```